# How print the data in the method on JFrame

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a void method that prints the data in a nice table in another class. I would like to ask how can I print the contents of this void method on a JFrame?

```
public void printInformation(Person[] data) {
for (int i=0, i<data.length' i++){
    System.out.println(data[i].getName() + " | " data[i].getSurname());
}
}
```

Comment: can you post code? How would you like the display to be printed on the JFrame, what have you tried so far that hasn't worked?

Comment: I want all of this information to be on the JFrame. Is it possible to transfer the data to JFrame by calling this method?

Comment: Look at @Zizhen Song's answer, that should work

Answer (score 1):

The data can be printed in JFrame by using the JTable class.

```
JTable table;
public void createTable(Person[] data) {
   String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Surname"};
   String[][] people = new String[data.length][2];
   for (int i=0, i<data.length, i++){
       people[i] = {data[i].getName(), data[i].getSurname());
   }
   table = new JTable(people, columnNames);
}
```

JTable have the constructor:

- JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)

You can create two arrays: one containing your data set and one containing the column names. Using the two arrays you can output a table in JFrame